# Enumeration of a custom object?

Tags: c#, enums

My goal is to create a type 'GameState' that has a set amount of different states.
I want it to act almost exactly like an enum set but I want there to be more than a single integer as data.

As an example, this is what I want to do:

```
switch(this.gameState)
{
   case(Wait):
      if(elapsedTime > gameState.TimeOutTime)
         //do stuff
   break;
   case(Play):
      if(elapsedTime > gameState.TimeOutTime)
         //do other stuff
   break;
}
```

So instead of GameState just being an enumeration of integers, I want it to contain variables like TimeOutTime and other useful information about that GameState.

Is there a way of adding depth to an enumeration or am I just attacking this problem at the wrong angle?

Comment: Why won't using your own custom type work? (E.g., a class) In this approach you'd set GameState equal to an enum, and you could have the logic you need in your class.

Comment: You could create a class named: GameState and have it contain lots of variables, you can also do: `List<GameState> gamestateList = new List<GameState>();`

Comment: If your code has a `switch` based on some type, chances are that [you are not doing OOP right](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are already good answers (@Selman22, @Max).

But I guess they are missing an important info: [You should **not** switch on type](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism). Use polymorphism instead.

So, based on your example, you should use something like this:

```
public abstract class GameState
{
    public int TimeOutTime { get; set; }

    public void CheckDoStuff()
    {
        if (elapsedTime > gameState.TimeOutTime) DoStuff();
    }

    protected abstract void DoStuff();
}

public WaitState : GameState
{
    protected override DoStuff()
    {
        // Do stuff (wait)
    }
}

public PlayState : GameState
{
    protected override DoStuff()
    {
        // Do other stuff (play)
    }
}
```

Note: I didn't add any `enum`, because I don't think one is really needed in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I was considering this but I guess it just took someone showing me it for me to realize that this is the obvious choice. Each state is going to have its own logic but will be used the same way. Polymorphism seems to be the best choice here.

Comment: @Dafeesh it usually is :) Also, be aware this is a really simple, naive implementation of a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) - I'm using simple inheritance and a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). If your use case is more complex, you may need to implement it more properly.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a `class`. You can't do that with `enums`, instead add a class and make the enum a property of your class.

```
class GameState
{
    public GameStateEnum State { get; set; }
    public int TimeOutTime { get; set; }
    // other properties...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easliy create a class for that like:

```
public class GameState
{
   public StateEnum State {get; set;}
   public DateTime TimeOutTime {get; set;}
}
```

Creating a list of GameStates would be easy like:

```
List<GameState> gameStateList = new List<GameState>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with .NET `enums` (you can with Java though)

Assuming you `elapsedTime` is a DateTime, something like:

using System;

```
public class GameState
{
    private readonly TimeOutTime _timeOutTime;

    public GameState(TimeOutTime timeOutTime)
    {
        _timeOutTime = timeOutTime;
    }

    public TimeOutTime TimeOutTime { get { return _timeOutTime; } }
}

public class TimeOutTime
{
    private readonly DateTime _dateTime;

    public TimeOutTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime(TimeOutTime timeOutTime)
    {
        return new TimeOutTime(timeOutTime);
    }

    public static implicit operator TimeOutTime(DateTime timeOutTime)
    {
        return new TimeOutTime(timeOutTime);
    }
}
```